# MySQL Group By Row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot-table, summarization

I have a table that looks like this:

---

```
Associate Pay_Code Hours    Site    Date       Week     Year
Bill    REG  8.0    US  3/3/2014    10      2014
Bill    REG  8.0    US  3/4/2014    10      2014
Bill    REG  8.0    US  3/5/2014    10      2014
Bill    REG  8.0    US  3/6/2014    10      2014
Bill    VTO  6.0    US  3/7/2014    10      2014
Bill    PERS 2.0    US  3/7/2014    10      2014
Mary    REG  8.0    Canada  3/3/2014    10      2014
Mary    REG  8.0    Canada  3/4/2014    10      2014
Mary    REG  8.0    Canada  3/5/2014    10      2014
Mary    REG  8.0    Canada  3/6/2014    10      2014
Mary    REG  6.0    Canada  3/7/2014    10      2014
Mary    PERS 2.0    Canada  3/7/2014    10      2014
Fred    REG  8.0    England 3/3/2014    10      2014
Fred    REG  8.0    England 3/4/2014    10      2014
Fred    REG  8.0    England 3/5/2014    10      2014
Fred    REG  8.0    England 3/6/2014    10      2014
Fred    REG  8.0    England 3/7/2014    10      2014
Wilma   REG  8.0    Jamaica 3/3/2014    10      2014
Wilma   REG  8.0    Jamaica 3/4/2014    10      2014
Wilma   REG  8.0    Jamaica 3/5/2014    10      2014
Wilma   REG  8.0    Jamaica 3/6/2014    10      2014
Wilma   REG  8.0    Jamaica 3/7/2014    10      2014
Wilma   OT   5.0    Jamaica 3/7/2014    10      2014
Jethro  REG  8.0    Africa  3/3/2014    10      2014
Jethro  REG  8.0    Africa  3/4/2014    10      2014
Jethro  REG  8.0    Africa  3/5/2014    10      2014
Jethro  REG  8.0    Africa  3/6/2014    10      2014
Jethro  REG  8.0    Africa  3/7/2014    10      2014
Jethro  OT   8.0    Africa  3/7/2014    10      2014
Frank   REG  8.0    Iraq    3/3/2014    10      2014
Frank   PERS 8.0    Iraq    3/4/2014    10      2014
Frank   PERS 8.0    Iraq    3/5/2014    10      2014
Frank   VACP 8.0    Iraq    3/6/2014    10      2014
Frank   VACP 8.0    Iraq    3/7/2014    10      2014
```

---

This query:

```
SELECT Pay_Code, Site, SUM(Hours), Week(Date,4), YEAR(Date)

FROM table

GROUP BY Pay_Code, Site, YEAR(Date), WEEK(Date,4)
```

Gives me:

```
Pay Code    Site    Sum of Hours     Week     Year
OT          Africa   8.0             10      2014 
            Jamaica  5.0             10      2014 
PERS        Canada   2.0             10      2014 
            Iraq     16.0             10      2014 
            US       2.0             10      2014 
REG         Africa   40.0             10      2014 
            Canada   38.0             10      2014 
            England  40.0             10      2014 
            Iraq     8.0             10      2014 
            Jamaica  40.0             10      2014 
            US       32.0             10      2014 
VACP        Iraq     16.0             10      2014 
VTO         US       6.0             10      2014
```

What I would like to do is to Group the Pay_Code Groups so that they can be further summarized. Something that looks like this:

```
Pay Code2           Pay Code    Site    Sum of Hours      Week     Year
OT                  OT          Africa   8.0              10      2014
                                Jamaica  5.0              10      2014
Paid Shrink         PERS        Canada   2.0              10      2014
                                Iraq     16.0             10      2014
                                US       2.0              10      2014
                    VACP        Iraq     16.0              10      2014
REG                 REG         Africa   40.0              10      2014
                                Canada   38.0              10      2014
                                England  40.0              10      2014
                                Iraq     8.0              10      2014
                                Jamaica  40.0              10      2014
                                US       32.0              10      2014
Unpaid Shrink       VTO             US       6.0             10      2014
```

The goal is to report the Pay_Code2 field by site, by week but the Pay_Code2 field does not exist in the table. Right now I query a large amount of data and use a Pivot Table to group my rows. I would like to do this in MySQL if possible.

Comment: What is `Paid Shrink`, `REG REG`, `Unpaid Shrink`?

Comment: Why don't you add a column "pay_code_2" or a lookup table?

Comment: @pce - I have RO to the table so I can't add any fields. I don't know the MySQL methods to setup the groups i.e. Paid Shrink = VACP + PERS, Unpaid Shrink = VTO + LOA, etc.

Comment: @bluefeet - All of the items under the Pay_Code2 header are grouped rows. For example, Paid Shrink = VACP + PERS, REG = REG, OT = OT, Unpaid Shrink = VTO + LOA + BER etc. Currently I am using a Pivot Table to group the rows together. I would like to do this using MySQL code if possible so that the work is done on the DB server and so that the query doesn't return so much data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to create a new category based on the PayCode values. You can try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Pay_Code = 'OT' THEN 'OT'
         WHEN Pay_Code IN ('VACP','PERS') THEN 'Paid Shrink'
         WHEN Pay_Code = 'REG' THEN 'REG'
         WHEN Pay_Code IN ('VTO','LOA','BER') THEN 'Unpaid Shrink'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
       END as PayCode_2
       ,YEAR(Date), WEEK(Date,4), SUM(Hours), Site, Pay_Code
FROM table
GROUP BY PayCode_2, Pay_Code, Site, YEAR(Date), WEEK(Date,4)
```